# How to perform correctly simulation of context data updates in React.js app using React context

Tags: reactjs, simulation, react-context

I have to develop a ReactJS application having internal "simulator" for frequent data updates.

Think of a need to simulate state and location updates for multiple entities (like, cars) being displayed in the app. While long term the data will come from the back end, the current project involves only the front end. We expect that the logic of the simulation will be a complex piece of software, requiring frequent updates.

The UI has almost no control over the data. 99% of the data updates come from within the simulator, and the UI components need to reflect the current state of the data. There is currently no need to persist any data after the app being closed.

From an initial research of how React context works, I found a solution that looks like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MyContext = React.createContext({
  mydata: []
});

export const MyContextProvider = () => {
    const [myData, setMyData] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
                // Here do the next simulation step and 
                // call 'setMyData' to update
            }
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [myData]);
  
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider
      value={{
        myData: myData
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default MyContext;

// In index.js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <MyContextProvider>
    <App />
  </MyContextProvider>
);
```

In this way, assuming I can recalculate the state correctly in the function called every second, all the components under  can access and render the context data.

Still I feel that this may not be the optimal solution: it ties the context update logic to a component, while the simulation logic is a separate "service", and the only thing logically connecting it to such a component would be the need to update the context.

Will be glad to get an expert opinion on better options to implement such a "simulator".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think tying some logic to a component be wrong but if you want to separate your logic from the component you can leverage the power of custom hooks. Just create a custom hook and move your logic into it, then return the fresh data to your component.
Still there are some considerations you may want to make:
Using context for making data available to the child components is a right choice but something like this is wrong:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setMyData(someValue); // infinite loop
}, [myData])
```

It will result in an infinite loop indeed.
I think using `setInterval` is useless in this case. If the data comes from server and you want to reflect the changes in the components you should use [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) or [websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

Comment: Hi, thanks. I my case, I hope I was able to avoid the infinite loop. When "mydata" changes, "useEffect" sets the timer callback in 1 sec, and further context changes are initiated from the timer callback.
I can tell that it works and I don't see performance issues.
But still will be glad to hear if there is a more elegant way.